# How much storage space in Trello?

Tags: trello, online-storage

How much storage space do I have in Trello? Also, is there a professional version for companies with 200 employees?

Answer (score 6):

Trello FAQ says:

> There is a 10mb file upload limit per attachment. It's not possible to upload attachments via the mobile site. There is no limit on the number of attachments you can have on a card or board. Neither is there an account data storage limit.